# Compare two numbers without comparative operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Is it possible to have a function which compares two numbers without comparative operators so that it returns 1 if they are equal and 0 if they are not? (No <, >, ==, etc.)

e.g.

$f(x, y) = ?$
$f(20, 20) = 1$
$f(15, 20) = 0$

It's possible to get 1 if they are equal -
$1 - (x-y)$
But I cannot figure any way to get 0 if they are not equal

Comment: Is using $\max$ and $\min$ allowed? Is absolute value allowed? Is bitshift allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If max and min are allowed:

$$f(a, b) = \lceil\frac{\max - \min}{\max - \min + 1}\rceil.$$

Note that you can implement max and min using bitwise operators or absolute values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375882/mathematically-find-max-value-without-conditional-comparison

Comment: There's no way to implement ceil is there though?

Comment: In integer division, usually in programming languages it's rounding to zero. So, there's an implicit floor there (assuming positive inputs

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical reasoning has a solution to this.

We use the Boolean Expression Q = A ⊙ B

This is the Boolean Expression for the XNOR (Exclusive NOR) gate.

Here's the Truth Table

[image]

Also this Boolean expression is equivalent to the "if and only if" statements in mathematical reasoning.

Thus the expression a $\iff$ b will solve your problem. We read it as "a iff b".

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678344/compare-two-integers-using-bit-operator for more.

Comment: Actually, you should accept this answer. It's much better. In code, you'll probably use the negation of XOR. (Small pedantic thing, I think your symbol $\oplus$ means XOR, not XNOR)

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminWang..

Comment: I accepted the other post as I was looking for a simple mathematical implementation, not a coding implementation. My understand is that you can only implement bitwise operations with sets and it gets messy.

Comment: Yes that's true Bitwise gets messy at times..